# Algorithm : how to organize database search with multiple parameters?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, algorithm, merge

I need to create a search script that would look into a table of house availability dates and match user search input.

**This is sample data:**

```
House is available for rent in these two date ranges: 

[0] => Array
(
  [start_date] => 2011-01-01
  [end_date] => 2011-03-31
  [nb_of_people] => 6
  [price_per_night] => 100
)

[1] => Array
(
  [start_date] => 2011-04-01
  [end_date] => 2011-04-30
  [nb_of_people] => 7
  [price_per_night] => 110
)
```

I have prepared script that merges continuous/overlapped dates in one db record, so the result would look like this:

```
(
  [start_date] => 2011-01-01
  [end_date] => 2011-04-30
  [availability_ids] => 0;1
)
```

---

### UPDATED:

*calculations were not clear so I updated the post:*

Lets say user searched for house:

dates: from 2011-03-28 to 2011-04-08, 
for 6 people, 
and he is willing to spend from $90 to $108 dollars per night.

**This is my manual calculations for this search:**

1. dates match our merged dates interval
2. total number of dates user wants to stay is: 11 days
3. price for the first period 2011-03-28 to 2011-03-31 is 3days * $100 = $300
4. price for the second period 2011-04-01 to 2011-04-08 is 8days * $110 = $880
5. total average price per night = 300 + 880 / 11 = $107.27
6. price and number of people matches user input, so we display this house

---

If you merge dates and calculate average price per night for the given period, search script should match array of data provided above.

My question is this: How would you organize data in database and how search script algorithm should look like to retrieve results from database instantly.

P.S. I am OK to run cron job to re-organize data on daily basis if needed.

Thanks for any advise.

Comment: Don't think the "Average" is computable here, in a sense that it remains fair. For example, if one costs 1/night and another 209, then the average is still 105, but to the user paying almost double per night doesn't make sense. You're better helped with a "x% deviation" approach. Is that ok for you?

Comment: Well, user will have to click on a house to book it. That way he will see full table of availability dates & prices. My mission is to retrieve this house for him in search results, since its actually matches his numbers. What would be your solution @Mel?

Comment: I would set a deviation, like 10%. So if the user indicates 105/night, we set the acceptable price range from 90%*105 to 110%*105. This is then easy to query in a database. You can also use only an upper limit, if you want to show all cheap ones. Or a 30% lower limit, vs 10% upper limit. Depends a bit. Like for me personally, if I want 500USD room, I don't need to see the 300USD ones, cause they're "below my standards".

Comment: Hello @Mel, I understand your point. Its my fault that I didn't mention about lowest and highest price user wants to pay for rent. We do have this option in search. I just updated my original post above. Please take a look. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have a fairly complicated problem on your hands.

You're assuming that the customers are all right with switching in the middle of their stay.  They might not want to.  The example you have has them moving.  Did you ask them whether this was all right?

You might also be assuming that they're all right with living in separate houses.  Is two houses with 3 spaces apiece fine, or do they want just one house where everyone can stay together?  Are they sharing quarters with people they don't know?

I'd look at your assumptions (those were just some examples; I'm sure there are more) and consider whether or not you want to mix in their preferences.  Then this will lead you to how you combine query results -- or more importantly, how you don't combine them.

Comment: Hello @John, Thanks for your ideas. We will assume that the owner of the house could not book his place, so he will be definitely OK to rent it for the period that brakes his availability dates. Nobody will ask clients to move out or stay in different houses. Its the same house, just different prices for different periods. And we need to find out if user's search matches combined average price. Please Note: I just updated information in my initial post. Please take a look.

Comment: If he wants to provide this option, he still has to code for the complex case and can simply provide options to exclude this event. Like I can choose for contigious flight or 1 or 2 lay overs. You still have to code for the possibility of lay overs.

Comment: @Mel:  It's handling both the layovers and no layovers that's really complex.  Assuming layovers isn't as complex as giving the option to exclude them.